# How to fix Chromecast in Chrome showing "available for specific video sites"?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

Every attempt to cast via Google Chrome (regular tab, YouTube, etc.) suddenly shows this message, is there any way to fix it?

[image: Casting tab available for specific video sites]
[image: Casting screen available for specific video sites]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various methods I've just restarted my streamer, and this immediately fixed it (I could once more cast whatever I want to the streamer). I hope it can help others.